# Interpreting pseudo-R² in GLMM

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, pseudo-r-squared

Different approaches to pseudo-R² naturally yield different results. For example, Nagelkerkes pseudo-R² tends to yield higher results than McFaddens pseudo-R².

As I am not a statistician, it thus can be somewhat difficult to interpret pseudo-R². In ecology (correct me if I am wrong), it is ± broadly accepted that a fair amount of the variability in the response variable is explained with McFaddens R² > 0.2, while a "good" Nagelkerkes R² is > 0.5.

When it comes to mixed models, I tried to use `r.squaredGLMM {MuMIn}`. However, I am quite unsure about the interpretation of the outcome. According to [Why are results different between MuMIn::r.squaredGLMM and piecwiseSEM::sem.model.fits?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316734/why-are-results-different-between-muminr-squaredglmm-and-piecwisesemsem-mode), `r.squaredGLMM` implements Schielzeth and Nakagawa's R2 for generalized linear mixed effects models.

I suppose that both can vary between 0 and 1. Can anyone indicate how to interpret conditional and marginal pseudo-R² of `r.squaredGLMM`?